# Understanding flow in javascript

Tags: javascript

very new to JS and just playing around with examples I have written from a book.
With the code below - why are my functions not being executed? I am calling them and the syntax is correct. If I place document.addEventListener ("DOMContentLoaded" , init , false) ;
then the init() function will execute but not the test() function.

I am also confused as to where the document.addEventListener should be placed normally and exactly what it means with regards to the init function. Should the init() function always be called first? What normally goes in an init()function?

Thanks in advance. Code below ;

```
function init() {
    var panel = document.getElementById("panel");
    panel.innerHTML = "Hello World";
}


function test() {
    var panel = document.getElementById("panel");
    panel.innerHTML = "See ya";

}
init();
test();
```

Comment: How do you know the functions are not being executed? What does the entire document look like? Are any errors shown in the JavaScript console?

Comment: A jsfiddle would be useful

Comment: because when i load the html page it is blank

Comment: The answer to most of your questions is "It depends when you are doing with it".

Comment: @DJC — That doesn't mean the function isn't executing. It might be executing and then throwing an error.

Comment: Where do you have these functions currently declared? it appears something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/wDTxC/ you want this http://jsfiddle.net/wDTxC/1/ using `window.onload=function` this will make your code execute on `window.onload` you can also add it to the `body` `onload` event.

Comment: @abc123 — The body element doesn't have an onload event. The onload attribute for it maps to the document's onload event.

Answer (score 3):

You are probably executing the functions before the DOM elements have been loaded. The page is read from top to bottom. If the function executes before the HTML is read, the element won't exist.

Many developers make the script the last element in the body to avoid this.

Or use an onload handler, like this

```
window.onload = function () {
  init();
  test();
}
```

The functions do not need to be defined in the handler

EDIT. It is also true that you are writing data to the same element, so only the second function will have a result you can see. You can write to a separate element, or do as one answer suggests and add the data together.

Comment: couldn't agree more.  You can also bind to the onload function of the body tag.  ;)

Comment: Hi Jeffman thanks for that - you are correct - I moved the script tag to the end of the body section and it worked. However - is this best practice as I have used some online tutorials in over the last couple of weeks and I thought they said to place it in the head section?

Comment: @abc123 — No, you can't. The `onload` *attribute* for the body element maps onto the onload *event* for the document.

Comment: #DJC there are arguments about best practice for this maneuver. Most tutorials and books I've seen put this stuff in the head. I usually do also. If I really need speed, I sometimes put some script immediately after the affected DOM elements.

Comment: @Quentin it works fine for me http://jsfiddle.net/wDTxC/2/

Comment: @abc123 — That's the onload **attribute**. Please reread my previous comment. Also please stop using intrinsic event attributes, this isn't the 1990s any more.

Comment: Ok thanks very much jeffman (and everybody else). I am now following this up with an even more stupid question - so should I remove the DOMContentLoaded part - as unless I call all functions within its parentheses, won't it then stop all functions other than init from running?

Comment: what i mean is - the only functions that seem to run are those called within the document.AddEventListener("DOMContentLoaded" ... ) part

Comment: Are you asking questions in the right answer? Brian S is probably not reading them.

Comment: Hi Jeffman sorry I was actually asking you. I guess the main query I have is why after loading the init function does it not move on to the other functions?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the methods are being called, but they are raising errors because they are called before the DOM is finished loading.  Under normal circumstances, script like this will be executed as soon as the browser reaches it, so if this happens before the DOM is loaded (which is usually the case), the calls to document.getElementById() will fail because the document hasn't been loaded.

You're close with your call to document.addEventListener ("DOMContentLoaded" , init , false); - this tells the browser to call init when the DOM has been loaded.  However, you're only calling init in this case, so test() doesn't get called.

I would suggest removing your inline calls to init(); and test();, then adding the following:

```
function onLoaded(){
    init();
    test();
}
```

and then calling onLoaded from your event listener:

```
document.addEventListener ("DOMContentLoaded" , onLoaded , false);
```

Comment: you aren't removing the eventListener...if you are going to recommend this road please make sure you show that removing eventListeners is important or else you'll end up with a memory leak.  I don't think this would be a preferred solution.

Comment: @abc123 — You end up with memory leaks if your function has a reference to the element to which it is bound and you are using IE. Just using `addEventListener` does not cause memory leaks. This *is* the preferred approach.

Comment: @Quentin after reading more you are absolutely correct! thanks for broadening my knowledge.

Comment: Thanks to both of you - I learned something new as well.